# Volley trying to use Youtube Data API

Tags: android, json, youtube, android-volley

i have a problem trying to retrieve some date from googleapis, youtubeapi.
here is the link:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUpXSJOEKMoOhdwdh_7AJ2Vg&key=SOMEKEY
```

If i go to any browser and paste that url i have all the data that i need, a json like this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/CokfSR1Ka3d1R0DGLPIfTD3IZqU\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 993,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/hYDAQqaQpnjwln2FQWxqH4pNDwM\"",
   "id": "VVVwWFNKT0VLTW9PaGR3ZGhfN0FKMlZnLk1OMXp4Vm5WWEZv",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-11-30T13:53:50.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCpXSJOEKMoOhdwdh_7AJ2Vg",
    "title": "Amaneciendo Con Dios - Celebrando La Vida Pastor General",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MN1zxVnVXFo/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MN1zxVnVXFo/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MN1zxVnVXFo/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "TaberTV",
    "playlistId": "UUpXSJOEKMoOhdwdh_7AJ2Vg",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "MN1zxVnVXFo"
    }
   }
  },`
}
```

And the json goes on.
When i try to retrieve it with volley i get this error:

```
12-01 10:54:08.082 3690-3690/com.tabernaculo.app E/Volley: [1] 4.onErrorResponse: Error:
```

My code to retrieve data with volley works with other websites, how can i make it work with youtube? This is how i send the url

```
urlEncoded = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId="+URLEncoder.encode(playListID,"UTF-8").toString()+"&key="+URLEncoder.encode(APIKEY,"UTF-8").toString();
```

I have tried pasting just the parameters without URLEncoder and there's no change.

Comment: Most likely your API key isn't correct. Try logging `urlEncoded` and making sure it's assembled correctly.

Comment: My API key is fine, i have a video player working with that API key.